# make asynchronous functions within for loop run in series

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

So in Node.js let's say I have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    someAsynchronousFunction(function(err,res) {
        // Do a bunch of stuff
        callback(null,res);
    });
}
```

But I want this to run synchronously.  I know this is not advised in Node JS, but I am just trying to understand the language.  I tried implementing the following solution, but it just ends up hanging during runtime:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var going = true;
    someAsynchronousFunction(function(err,res) {
        // Do a bunch of stuff
        callback(null,res);
        going = false;
    });
    while (going) {

    }
}
```

What is going wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best way to do that is to use the *async* library.

```
async.timesSeries(1000, function(n, next){
    someAsynchronousFunction(next);
});
```

Or you can do that with [*async.series()* function](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series).

**.times() documentation :** http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.timesSeries

Comment: Awesome, I was actually looking for an Async function to do this, but I could not find it.

Comment: Did you mean timesSeries()?  Also, form a performance standpoint on strictly asynchronous loop in parallel.  Is it faster to run Async.times() or simply do the for loop?

Comment: Yes ! Because *.times()* run in parallel. For the faster way, I don't know. I think it must be similar, but we need some benchmarks to concluded that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using Promises to generate a sequential execution of them thanks to `Array#reduce` :

```js
// Function that returns Promise that is fllfiled after a second.
function asyncFunc (x){
  return new Promise((rs, rj)=>{
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      console.log('Hello ', x);
      rs();
    }, 1000)
  });
}
// Generate an array filed with values : [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
Array.from({length : 1000}, (el, i)=> i)
// loop througth the array chaining the promises.
.reduce( (promise, value) => 
   promise.then(asyncFunc.bind(null, value))
, Promise.resolve(null));
```